# Проверка на вхождение определенного символа 2 и более раз вподряд

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как с помощью регулярного выражения проверить на вхождения 2 и более раз определенного символа? То есть, я хочу чтобы в логине символы "-." могли присутствовать но только не должны идти в подряд.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В самое начало регулярного выражения вставьте:

```
(?!.*--)
```

Для подробной информации почитайте про позиционные проверки в регулярных выражениях.

Данная конструкция применима ко всем языкам, где используются Perl совместимые регулярные выражения, но лучше конечно конечно уточнить наличие поддержки в целевом языке.
Конструкция:

```
(?! ... )
```

Означает негативную опережающую проверку, что на человеческим языке обозначает, что из данной позиции совпадения надо заглянуть вперед, дабы удостовериться, что все что справа НЕ соответствует регулярному выражению в скобках. В нашем случае будем проверять, что справа нет два тире подряд.

```
.*
```

Это любой символ сколько угодно раз, грубо говоря в нашем контексте это просто пропуск не интересующего нас текста. Если текст может содержать переводы строк, то для регулярного выражения надо включить флаг DOTALL.

```
--
```

Это собственно и есть требование двух тире подряд.
Конструкция в целом обозначает: смотрим вперед и если видим два тире подряд, то данная позиция не должна войти в совпадение.

Если в языке не поддерживаются позиционные поверки, но поддерживаются сохраняющие группы, то можно написать примерно так:

```
^(?:(--)|-|[other symbols])$
```

Наличие двух тире в первой группе означает, что два тире есть в тексте.

Comment: @ReinRaus, а что это за выражение? Кто его понимает? Например, egrep не понимает.

--

Я понимаю, Вы большой спец (без всякой иронии) в regexp-ах, но не могли бы Вы более подробно объяснять примеры в своих ответах (хотя, что для меня, например, в regexp-ах неочевидно, то для других программистов, вполне возможно, элементарно). 

От этого их ценность для базы знаний ХК многократно возрастет.

Comment: @avp, grep поддерживает позиционные проверки

Comment: Только вот проверок будет две. Одна, чтобы проверить наличие "-", другая -- отсутствие "--".

Comment: @alezlz, не совсем уловил мысль- почему должно быть две проверки?  
Например их исходно есть выражение:  

    ^[-a-z0-9]+$
Изменив его начало:  

    (?!.*--)^[-a-z0-9]+$
Мы получим, что наличие двух тире подряд не позволяет тексту пройти проверку на соответствие.

Comment: @ReinRaus Вспылил, был неправ. Извиняюсь

Comment: @ReinRaus, grep (в ububtu) таких выражений вообще не понимает 

(символом `> ` обозначаю ввод, а `< ` вывод grep)

    avp@avp-ubu1:~$ grep '(?!.*--)'
    > (?!--)
    < (?!--)
    > (?!qwe--)hhshsh
    < (?!qwe--)hhshsh
    > aahha
    > 17717
    avp@avp-ubu1:~$ 

egrep понимает скобки, но не `?!` в начале в описываемом Вами смысле

    avp@avp-ubu1:~$ egrep '(?!.*--)'
    > a-b
    > !--
    < !--
    > aaa!bbb--n
    < aaa!bbb--n
    > xxx--n
    > xxx!--n
    < xxx!--n
    avp@avp-ubu1:~$ 

Никакого отрицания `--`, все наоборот и `!` это для egrep (и grep) не метасимвол.